# Django-rest serializer returning code instead of list of objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint in my Django-rest application in which I expect to receive the following get response:

```
{
    "my_objects": [
    {
      "my_object_order": 1,
      "related_topics": [{"title": "my_title", "subtitle": "my_subtitle"}, {"title": "my_title2", "subtitle": "my_subtitle2"}],
      "collected_at": "2016-05-02T20:52:38.989Z",
    }]
}
```

In order to achieve that, below you can observe my **serializers.py**

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyTopic
        fields = ["title", "subtitle"]

class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    related_topics = TopicSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
        fields = ("my_object_order",
                  "related_topics")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Saving serialized data
        """
        related_topics_list = validated_data.pop("related_topics", [])
        obj = MyObject.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for topics_data in related_topics_list:
            MyTopic.objects.create(trend=trend, **topics_data)
        return obj
```

As suggested, here you can see my **models.py**

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    my_object_order = models.IntegerField()
    collected_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.story_title


class MyTopic(models.Model):
    my_obj = models.ForeignKey(MyObject, related_name="related_topics")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Below you have the excerpt from my **views.py**

```
def get(self, request):
    params = request.QUERY_PARAMS
    # Filtering data
    obj_list = my_fun(MyObject, params)
    response = {"my_objects": obj_list.values("my_object_order",
                                             "collected_at",
                                             "related_topics")}
    return Response(response)
```

I have looked on the documentation, however I am confused/not understanding fundamentally what I should do.

Comment: Please add the models and the implementation of `my_fun` as well.

Comment: You are missing a "`]`" bracket in your first and last code block

Comment: Implementation of `my_fun` is not relevant. If it was, you would have access to it already. Models are relevant indeed, I will add in a bit.

Comment: @AaronLelevier, this comment is more related to my response data, which has nothing to do with my real problem reported here. But I can fix that, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira take a look on this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: @AndersonLima, I read it but I cannot properly understand what I should do in this case. Do you think you can elaborate something on this to help me here?

Comment: Please add the actual response you are seeing

Comment: @RicardoSilveira try setting class Meta from MyObjectSerializer with depth = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in views.py, you are not using actually the serializer at all. You are just filter some data and return whatever values you get from database (hence the ids only).

I suggest you to check [Generic Class Based Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

```
from myapp.models import MyObject
from myapp.serializers import MyObjectSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class MyObjectListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer
```

Also if you need any filtering check documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/). Basically you can filter by fields from model with this snippet

```
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filter_fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

PS: You can do the view as normal function, but you have to handle yourself filtering/serialization part, the code may not look as cleaner as you get with class based views.